# Unhandled Runtime Error next.js with tailwindcss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I watch one courses about nft marketplace. In design use tailwind css. I do what do in video. But I get error. I cannot know where this was and how to fix it. On browser get this:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

and console get this:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with className={condition && value}, pass className={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
    at img
    at ImageElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:575:11)
    at span
    at Image (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:18:11)
    at div
    at nav
    at Navbar (webpack-internal:///./components/Navbar.jsx:95:88)
    at div
    at c (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next-themes\dist\index.js:1:291)
    at exports.ThemeProvider (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next-themes\dist\index.js:1:3566)      
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:19:18)
    at StyleRegistry (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:671:34)
    at AppContainer (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:321:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:350:57)
    at div
    at c (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next-themes\dist\index.js:1:291)
    at exports.ThemeProvider (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next-themes\dist\index.js:1:3566)      
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:19:18)
    at StyleRegistry (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:671:34)
    at AppContainer (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:321:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:350:57)
    at div
    at Body (C:\Users\Feruz\Desktop\crypto\nft-marketplace\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:596:21)
```

I try change className properties. But it cannot help me. Here my github [repo](https://github.com/Feruz00/nft-marketplace).

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: I didnt know where was be error? For that I add in github repo for helping find current error which pages or which components. I will be happy for fix these errors

Comment: According to the error, the issue seems to come from the `Navbar` component where `next/image` is used.

Comment: I try change classNames all pages, components. do className={theme === "light" ? "filter invert" : false} and empty classes do className="". when I complete build navbar, create nft page all work well. But when run server today get error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error. When looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes#avoid-hydration-mismatch), the code should be changed to this:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  // const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);
  if (!mounted) return null;
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute="class">
      <div className="dark:bg-nft-dark bg-white min-h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="pt-65">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
      <Script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7409f70bd9.js" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

and it works.